# CodeIgniter form validation doesn't work

Tags: codeigniter

When I use functions in CodeIgniter form validation nothing happens (there are no problems with native CodeIgniter rules such as required).

Example:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'title', 'trim|strip_tags');
```

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter's form validation rules support any of the validation rules found in the [form validation library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rulereference), [prepping functions](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#preppingreference) and any native PHP functions that permit one parameter.

So, native PHP, such as `trim` or `strip_tags`, can be used:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'title', 'trim|strip_tags');
```

---

If a native PHP function is to be used with more than one parameter, or additional functionality is required, than a [callback](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks) should be used.

**Validation rule**

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'title',
                                    'trim|callback_custom_strip_tags');
```

**Callback function**

```
public function custom_strip_tags($str)
{
    // Allow <p> tags, strip all other tags
    return strip_tags($str, '<p>'); 
}
```